# In Ruby On Rails, how can I remove views related to a specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I created this post_controller earlier in the project but I decide to destroy it later.

Then I use

```
rails destroy controller post_controller
```

to remove the controller. But I also want to remove the views that attach to this controller.
In this case, they are the erb files in the app/views/post folder. How can I remove those erb files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `rails d scaffold post` but be warned this will destroy the rest of the scaffolded elements including any models/routes/assets etc.  Here is the full list of what it will destroy:

```
⌘ ~/testapp/ rails d scaffold post
  invoke  active_record
  remove    migration.rb
  remove    app/models/post_controller.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/unit/post_controller_test.rb
  remove      test/fixtures/post_controllers.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :post_controllers
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  remove    app/controllers/post_controllers_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  remove      app/views/post_controllers
  remove      app/views/post_controllers/index.html.erb
  remove      app/views/post_controllers/edit.html.erb
  remove      app/views/post_controllers/show.html.erb
  remove      app/views/post_controllers/new.html.erb
  remove      app/views/post_controllers/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/functional/post_controllers_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  remove      app/helpers/post_controllers_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  remove        test/unit/helpers/post_controllers_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  remove      app/assets/javascripts/post_controllers.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  remove      app/assets/stylesheets/post_controllers.css.scss
  invoke  scss
```

**Edit:**

To clarify, `rails d` is just shorthand for `rails destroy`. It can also be used as `rails generate`/ `rails g`.

Comment: What if I have already used destroy controller command? The controller is gone but the views are still there.

Comment: You can run rails d all day long even if whatever you are destroying doesn't exist. Rails will still attempt to destroy everything even if it isn't there, or some parts are missing.

Comment: Try running rails d scaffold somerandomnamethatdoesnotexist to see.